# How to get the textual representation of an LLVM IR instruction?

Tags: llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-ir

If `I` is of type `llvm::Instruction`, we can print out the same in human-readable form (textual representation) by `errs() << I;`

I want the assign the exact same representation to a `std::string` to C type string. How can I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, LLVM provides a string stream as well:

```
#include <llvm/Support/raw_ostream.h>
```

Use it like this:

```
std::string str;
llvm::raw_string_ostream(str) << I;

// use str
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into some problems using @eush77's answer. Here is my fix.

```cpp
std::string str;
llvm::raw_string_ostream ss(str);
ss << I;
errs() << ss.str() << "\n";
```